# Equivalent of like '%%' for contains(column-name,'%%')

Tags: sql-server

This is my following query:

```
  select Top 100 * from TweetEntity where contains (HashTag,'')
```

I get an error saying.

```
 Null or empty full-text predicate.
```

Then I changed my query :

```
   select Top 100 * from TweetEntity where contains (HashTag,'%%'). I got no results.
```

I expected it to run.
What is the equivalent of (using contains):

```
 select Top 100 * from TweetEntity where HashTag like '%%' ?
```

how ever this works returning records:

```
   select Top 100 * from TweetEntity where contains(HashTag,'gaza')
```

where as

```
  select Top 100 * from TweetEntity where contains(HashTag,'a') - this doesnot return any records.
```

Comment: Are you using a full-text index on that column?

Comment: Yes. i am using full text index on that column.

Comment: select Top 100 * from TweetEntity where contains (HashTag,'%a%') = returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`Full text Search` is a feature to do `Language Specific Search`.

The search may ignore the literal strings in the data and search for a specific word in a language , (Inflectional forms of a specific word, Synonymous  etc) which is specific to a language.

Here in your query you are looking for  the Letter "`A"` which isnt a word in english, its an alphabet but alone it doesn't mean anything. It is more like a pattren in a string for that purpose you should use `LIKE` key word along with wildcard `%` which will bring back the string value  `James W Brown`.

On the other hand if you a wanted to use FTS to find all the possible `James` in your database then FTS can be handy. By doing a THESAURUS search on James which will bring back Jim, Jimmy, Jimmie etc but then again you will have to edit the XML files under FDData for a specific language to make this happen.

`A` , `The` etc are considered to be noise words and they are ignored in FTS.

Answer (score 1):

You will never be able to search for "a". This is going to be included in the default stop-word list for English along with other common superfluous words such as "an", "the", etc. If you want to search for "a" you will need to create a custom stop-word list that excludes that.

Comment: why cant i search? I should be able to search for any word/letter, a text or a string.

Comment: As the answerer explained, full text search is for finding meaningful data.  "A" is noise as far as a search is concerned.  Imagine typing into google "where can I find a dog sheltor near nowheresville" - in such a search specific words add no value to the search, so they are dropped.  Your search might actually end up being performed on something like "dog sheltor nowheresville".  "A" isn't a word that provides meaning, if you need to get results with "A" do a like, but performance is potentially going to be terrible.